# Problems while building HiveDB in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hive

I am trying to build HiveDB project from the [HiveDB Github](https://github.com/britt/hivedb) in eclipse. I was able to successfully clone the project from the link. However, the project is unable to add the maven dependencies automatically, when I am trying to convert it into a maven project and building it. This is causing a huge number of errors in the code.

[image: Missing Dependency]

Is there any way to fix it? 
I tried doing a maven-clean and build again but it resulted in error. The following is the screenshot of the same.

[image: Error]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should start to create a local repository - use [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) for this, and if you can't find a library from maven repo, put it manually in the local repo. It will save a lot of your time.

And it seems you have another the compilation issue - not able to get JDK?
You should put something like this :

```
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
              <fork>true</fork>
              <executable>D:\jdk1.7.49\bin\javac.exe</executable>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
```